# Target Framework field dead

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, frameworks

I start Visual Studio 2012 for Win8, select C# for New Project, Windows Run Time Component, and then simply when I type `"cw+TAB+TAB" to print "Console.WriteLine();"`

This line appears: `global::System.Console.WriteLine();`  My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        global::System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The following errors appear:

```
Error 1  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" ,
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
```

The answers to these errors are are all the same online: I have to roll the ".NetFramework" back form 4.5 to 4.0 - However, when I go to the Properties of Solution Explorer, the target framework is blank and disabled. I can not do anything to change it, so how can I fix this problem?

It's possible that the solution to the errors lies in more than just changing the NET Framework, feel free to share all you know about this problem.

Comment: Win8 apps run off a different runtime than regular .net apps. If you want to use a `Console` you probably want to use an edition that runs off the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, at least the Express editions (haven't tried Pro+), ships in multiple versions - `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8` is specifically for building Win8 apps (those *Windows Store* apps, formerly referred to as "Metro" apps). Win8 apps run off a different runtime than the CLR and that doesn't exist in earlier framework versions, hence the blocked target framework drop-down.

If you're looking for the "traditional" IDE which allows you to build WinForms, WPF and Console apps, you need `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Desktop`.

If you're looking for Web development, you need `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Web`.

Comment: Thank You! I find this helpful!